# How do I fix the error "Windows cannot find 'excel'." when trying to export a CDK report to Excel?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, windows-registry

When attempting to export a report from CDK we get the error "Windows cannot find 'excel'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again." This is a Windows 10 PC running Office 365 installed from an E3 subscription. CDK runs on the IE11 browser framework and we are attempting to export the report using a button on the interface explicitly for this purpose "Export to Excel." I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Office and also ran the full Office repairs and the problem persists. I had a similar problem on another machine and discovered a registry key with a path to an empty excel.exe file (0kb) in the user's

> AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Office.Desktop_8wekyb3d8bbwe

folder. I corrected this to point to the correct location of excel.exe and it now works, but I am not finding a similar reference in the registry of this particular computer and other references in the registry to the excel.exe file appear to be correctly pointing to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16

I also tried adding this location to the system path but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

> When attempting to export a report from CDK we get the error "Windows cannot find 'excel'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again." This is a Windows 10 PC running Office 365 installed from an E3 subscription.

I am going to assume the entire error message is as follows:

> Windows cannot find "c:\program files\microsoft
> office\root\office16\winword.exe" Make sure you typed the name
> correctly, and then try again.'

If that is indeed the case.  The solution to this problem is simple.  You must update AVG or Avast.  Microsoft confirm on June 12th 2020 this problem was caused by specific versions of AVG or Avast.

> This issue has been resolved by Avast. This issue only affected
> devices with certain versions of Avast or AVG applications and was
> addressed with an update to their respective products. For more
> information on this, please see Avast's forum post [here](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=233129.msg1549776#msg1549776). Note No
> update is needed for Windows or Microsoft Office to address this
> issue.

Source: [Error when attempting to open any Microsoft Office application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/resolved-issues-windows-10-2004#435msgdesc)

Comment: I am unable to view the Avast forum thread at this time, when I get a chance in the future, I will update my answer to include the relevant information from it.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. The error is exactly as originally stated: "Windows cannot find 'excel'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."

We are not running either Avast or AVG.

Comment: What security software are you using?  What version of Windows are you using?